# How to compile a file with babel CLI

Tags: node.js, babeljs, transpiler

## I'm trying to compile a simple `es6` file with babel CLI

Given the details below: what's going wrong?

```
$ node --version
v5.0.0

$ npm --version
3.3.6

$ npm init
$ npm install --save-dev babel-cli

$ echo -e 'import url from "url"\nconsole.log(`2+2=${2+2}`)' > script.js

$ ./node_modules/.bin/babel  script.js 
import url from "url";
console.log(`2+2=${ 2 + 2 }`);
```

In other words: **I put in ES6 and I get out ES6** (albeit with slightly different spacing, and semicolons added). I'm expecting to see imports converted to requires, and to see my back-ticks disappear.

That is: **I want ES5 out**.

## What do I need to do differently?

Comment: What version of Babel? They very recently [completely changed](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/) how things work

Comment: For the record, 6.1 (Another way to say it: the commands shown above were run at the time of my question.)

Comment: This question is asked multiple times per day. Please use the search or at least browse the `babeljs` tag (I also suggest to read the *tag descriptions* of the tags you add)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Babel version 6 ships "without any default transforms". You can read more about the changes in [this blog post](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6/)

To transpile es6 to es5 you will need to do the following:

1. run `npm i --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`
2. Create a `.babelrc` file in the root of your project with the following:

   {

   ```
      "presets": ["es2015"]
   ```

   }

There's a lot of configuration you can do on top of that, but that should atleast get you started.

Comment: That's great -- thanks!

Comment: No problem! Ran into the same thing when version 6 was released.

Answer (score 1):

The trick: need to pass `--presets "es2015"` as an argument to babel.

As in:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/babel  --presets "es2015" script.js 
"use strict";

var _url = require("url");

var _url2 = _interopRequireDefault(_url);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

console.log("2+2=" + (2 + 2));
```